# CSS - Playbill Background Not Passing Check for HW?

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have reached out to my professor and fellow classmates; as well as, I have also re-read the chapter twice to find the answer. We are using the book: *HTML5 & CSS by Carey 7th ed.*

Currently, the playbill background is not passing the check. This is what Cengage is telling me:

[Cengage Check pt 1; overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It5Ii.png)

[Cengage Check pt 2; my current site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmOli.png)

[Cengage Check pt 3; solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vh8Z.png)

The description on what to do is as follows:

> Playbill Background Each playbill section is identified by a different
> ID value ranging from play1 to play4. Create style rules that set a
> different background color for each playbill using the following
> background colors:
>
> ID: play1 set to hsl(240, 100%, 88%)
>
> ID: play2 set to hsl(25, 88%, 73%)
>
> ID: play3 set to hsl(0, 100%, 75%)
>
> ID: play4 set to hsl(296, 86%, 86%)
>
> Each playbill section heading will also have a different font. For the
> h1 headings within the four different playbills, create style rules to
> apply the following font stacks:
>
> ID: play1 set to Champagne, cursive
>
> ID: play2 set to Grunge, ‘Times New Roman’, Times, serif
>
> ID: play3 set to Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif
>
> ID: play4 set to Dobkin, cursive

This is my current code:

```
/* Section Styles */
section.playbill h1{
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px 0px 10px 20px;
}

#play1{
  background-color: hsl(240, 100%, 88%);
}

#play2{
  background-color: hsl(25, 88%, 73%);
}

#play3{
  background-color: hsl(0, 100%, 75%);
}

#play4{
  background-color: hsl(296, 86%, 86%);
}

#play1 h1{
  font-family: champagne, cursive;
}

#play2 h1{
  font-family: Grunge, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#play3 h1{
  font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}

#play4 h1{
  font-family: Dobkin, cursive;
}
```

Comment: Good to have you here Julie. The way this question is written, I have difficulty understanding the issue. CSS without HTML is not very meaningful. Which objects are the styles assigned to? 

Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question itself. This will help you get useful answers quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following at the end of the code:

```
#play1,#play2,#play3,#play4 {
   margin:0px !important;
}

h1 { 
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
}
```